# Implementing horizontal/vertical finger swipe scrolling in android honeycomb webview/webkit?

Tags: android, html, webkit, webview, android-3.0-honeycomb

I am planning to implement Honeycomb tablet application based on WebView (so, basically it'll be a **HTML5 web based application** made only for **tablet**).

I am looking to implement horizontal and vertical scrolling by swiping finger. For better understanding I created sample outline.

[image: Horizontal Scrolling by Swiping]

---

This image shows something similar to Honeycomb's native setting activity with left and right page vertically scrollable
[image: Vertical Scrolling by Swiping]

Any kind of guides or resources are welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4):

> iScroll 4 is a complete rewrite of the original [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll) code. The script development began because mobile webkit (on iPhone, iPad, Android) does not provide a native way to scroll content inside a fixed width/height element. This unfortunate situation prevents any web-app to have a `position:absolute` header and/or footer and a scrolling central area for contents.
>
> While latest Android revisions are supporting this functionality (although support is not optimal), Apple seems reluctant to add one finger scrolling to divs...

Comment: Thanks, I took a look at it which is for vertical scrolling. I'm considering to use that.

Comment: Just wanted to update on this issue - we've used iScroll for relatively large app for iOS and Android. In the end, it produced lot more headaches than it solved. Don't get me wrong, iScroll is a nice library, it works well, but it has shortcomings. So, you should examine this thoroughly before choosing such library. Just take it as a warning. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, After using it in a larger application, I too found it to be more problematic, if you are building something of reasonable size, avoid iScroll.

Comment: so what did you use instead?

Comment: I used jQuery mobiles implementation for the supported devices and fell back to static header and footer for all other devices.

Answer (score 5):

*Here is what I have found so far:*

It depends on how you want to implement scrolling. If you want to attached swiping event, thats the easiest way to implement using well known libraries:

- **[jqTouch](http://jqtouch.com/)** - It has swipe left and right event which can be hooked to scroll left or right (it seems all the webkit based animations work only on iOS devices). *Please note that project is still in beta and not highly active.* EDIT: this is also part of Sencha Labs - who actively maintains Sencha Touch.
- **[Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/)** - They have better support for almost everything in mobile and tablet. *(Note: It's free for opensource apps but not for commercial apps - EDIT: they actually have commercial license. see their site for more info on licensing)*
- **[jQueryMobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc1/docs/api/events.html)** - They are very stable (in RC1 as of now), and has swipe left and right event, but I could not find swipe up or down. If you just need swipe left right, tap, tap hold, then go with jQM. They have the best community support.
- **RAW JS** - Finally, if you want something raw javascript, visit [HTML5Rocks article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touch.html) to have better in-depth idea about how touch event works.

I hope it helps. I'm still struggling to implement scroll up down, since I don't want to wait for swipe to end, instead I am trying to implement instant scroll feedback, getting very close using RAW JS coordinates, but not satisfactory.

Answer (score 5):

Hammer JS has been useful for me:

http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/

Comment: JS libs has come a long way since I encountered the issue. Thanks for sharing Ian.

Comment: No worries, just thought I would add just in case other people come across this thread.

Answer (score 2):

From the creators of iScroll, **SwipeView** seems a nice dedicated alternative. Have a look at [demo 1](http://cubiq.org/dropbox/SwipeView/demo/inline/) and [demo 2](http://cubiq.org/dropbox/SwipeView/demo/gallery/).

I have not tested yet, but I will surely. Since demos behave well on my iPad.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this library quite useful: https://github.com/cubiq/2-way-iScroll

It handles the case of vertical scroll and horizontal swipe.